# Mudando size do JOptionPane.showInputMessage

Tags: java, swing, gui

Tentei vários métodos como setPrefferedSize , setSize com/sem pack() mas nada parece afetar o JoptionPane

código:

```
        selectProcess = new JOptionPane();
    selectProcess.showInputDialog(null,"Please select game process","Select" , JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null ,processes.toArray(),null);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teria como deixar maior para a list mostrar mais de um por vez?

Comment: Tentou usar o método `setMinimumSize`?

Comment: tambem tentei, mas nada.

Comment: Realmente não vai adiantar muita coisa. Esse método é estático, e ele recria um `JOptionPane` internamente. Recomendo se possível reproduzir o código alterando a propriedade de tamanho do `JOptionPane`. Dê uma olhada no código fonte e verá: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cjavax.swing.Icon%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

Comment: Não existe nenhuma alternativa ao JOptionPane? Quero dizer, alguma outra biblioteca que faça a mesma coisa, mas que forneça ao desenvolvedor mais recursos.

Comment: Teria como criar um voce mesmo, que é o que vou fazer.. achei que daria para alterar e economizar linhas.

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma pesquisada no google e acabei achando essa solução. Vê se pode te ajudar.

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(args);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parent, title);
dialog.setSize(size);
dialog.show();
```

> http://www.coderanch.com/t/336475/GUI/java/size-JOptionpane-showOptionDialog